# Minha animação não esta funcionando quando passo o mouse

Tags: html, css, animação, css-transições, transição

Boa noite!

Estou querendo fazer um site e em uma parte dele estou querendo fazer uma animação de fadeIn com css, quando o usuário passa o mouse na DIV aparece outra mais não de uma forma "seca" e sim com alguma transição. Porém estou passando por uma dificuldade, já coloquei o animation na classe pai, mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço!

segue abaixo o código HTML e CSS que fiz

[image: Essa é a foto sem animação]

[image: Essa é a foto com animação]

```css
.minha-foto {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 325px;
  max-height: 325px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px; 
}

.minha-foto .redes-sociais {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%);
    display: none;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}

.minha-foto .redes-sociais ul {
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 0;
}

 .minha-foto .redes-sociais ul li {
        margin-left: 10px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
}

 .minha-foto .redes-sociais ul li a i {
          font-size: 30px;
          color: #fff;
}

 .minha-foto .redes-sociais:hover ul li:first-child {
    background: #3074B3;
}

.minha-foto .redes-sociais:hover ul li:nth-child(2) {
    background: #575EA4;
}

 .minha-foto .redes-sociais:hover ul li:last-child {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%, #e6683c 25%, #dc2743 50%, #cc2366 75%, #bc1888 100%);
}

 .minha-foto:hover .redes-sociais {
  display: flex;
}

 .minha-foto:hover .redes-sociais ul li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-5 minha-foto offset-md-2 my-auto" style="background-image:url('//localhost:3000/godoyportfolio/wp-content/themes/godoy/inc/img/eu-4.jpeg')">
      <div class="redes-sociais">
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>                </a></li>
             <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square">               </i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>              </a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara primeiro, vc tem que por `position:relative` no container da foto, assim o *overlay* da sombra que está dentro do container não cobre a tela inteira. Depois, `display` não é uma propriedade "animável" vc não pode animar `display`, uma sugestão é animar usando `opacity`, assim a imagem fica transparente, e no hover vc mostra colocando `opacity:1`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim como o `display` o `float` tb é uma propriedade que não pode ser animada por exemplo. Confira aqui uma lista de todas as propriedades que são "animáveis" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

```css
.minha-foto {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 325px;
    max-height: 325px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px; 

    position: relative;
  }
  
  .minha-foto .redes-sociais {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%);
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 1s opacity linear;
  }
  
  .minha-foto .redes-sociais ul {
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0;
  }
  
   .minha-foto .redes-sociais ul li {
          margin-left: 10px;
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
opacity: 0;
transition: 1s opacity linear;
  }
  
   .minha-foto .redes-sociais ul li a i {
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #fff;
  }
  
   .minha-foto .redes-sociais ul li:first-child {
      background: #3074B3;
  }
  
  .minha-foto .redes-sociais ul li:nth-child(2) {
      background: #575EA4;
  }
  
   .minha-foto .redes-sociais ul li:last-child {
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f09433 0%, #e6683c 25%, #dc2743 50%, #cc2366 75%, #bc1888 100%);
  }
  
   .minha-foto:hover .redes-sociais {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
   .minha-foto:hover .redes-sociais ul li {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-5 minha-foto offset-md-2 my-auto" style="background-image:url(https://placekitten.com/350/350)">
  <div class="redes-sociais">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>                </a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square">               </i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>              </a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Os botões não desvanecem ao sair com o mouse.

Comment: @CypherPotato aqui funcionou normal, como no demostrado no gif. Não entendi bem o que vc quis dizer sobre os botões... pode me explicar melhor para eu verificar?

Comment: No GIF o glitch também ocorre. Ao sair com o mouse da imagem, a sobreposição preta desvanece, no entanto, os botões sociais simplesmente somem por imediato.

Comment: @CypherPotato vc tinha razão cara, não tinha reparado. O problema era que o elemento não tinha background, o background só aparecia no hover, então tinha a transição suave no elemento, o que não tinha era a transição no  background dos botões. Vou só retirar o background do `:hover` e resolveu  valeu o toque

Comment: Entendi cara, muito obrigado pela ajuda, salvou :)

Comment: @FelipeGodoy sem problemas meu caro, tmj